# Cluster with t2.micro instances in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon Web Services (AWS) & I am using the free tier t2.micro right now ( 1 CPU and 1 GB memory).  Doing some backtesting/ simulation stuff and it seems free tier is quite inadequate. Pretty slow actually. Thus thinking of options which will help me to run my code at a faster speed for few hours.

Option 1 : I can 1 buy CPU optimized/ higher Memory instance ( 4 cores and 4 GB RAM for example ) and then make an image of my t2.micro and run my stuff in that new one. It will be expensive though if I keep it running, so I need to "stop" the instance when I am not working  ( or nothing is running ) to reduce the cost.

Option 2 : I can buy spot instances. I am not sure how to use the CPU and RAM of that spot instance from my existing t2.micro. Can I create a temporary grid/cluster where my Head Node will be running in my t2.micro but compute node will be the spot instance ( higher CPU and RAM ), thus all my calculations, etc will be using the spot instance.

My question : Is the Option 2 possible ? I program everything in python and I have all the relevant softwares/python IDEs etc are already installed in my t2.micro instance.

Any existing grid/cluster software I can use right now ? I don't know C++, Csharp, Java etc. Know only phython & R so any programming stuff I need to do to build a grid/cluster must use Python :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The simple answer for the question is Yes! You can SSH into the spot instance from you t2.micro just like you access your t2.micro. I'm not sure what you mean by grid/cluster software, do you want to deploy a distributed system like hadoop?

Comment: it sounds like you want `EMR` because afaik `EC2` is just one instance. You could spin up several `EC2` instances i.e a fleet and then distribute your code from the `t2` instance but why is the real question?

Comment: Be sure you understand how CPU credits work on t2 instances, before you conclude that they are "slow."  A t2 machine after 24 hours running but idle (near 0% CPU utilization for 24 hours) can do much more work than a newly-launched t2.

Comment: @ Ding. Actually all my code etc are in EBS volume which comes with t2.micro..When I want to run my program from t2.micro ( 1 CPU and 1 GB RAM), I want to avail for example 8 CPUs and 16 GB RAM and that program will finish within an hour. Mine are need based running. It's not running throughout the day. For example, I want to backtest lots of stock or forex time series, I code stuff in python and I want to run the backtesting but I want to finish it as soon as possible. So I need higher CPUs and high RAM just for an hour or 2 hours max at a time..How can I do that ?

Comment: @ Dmitry..actually EMR looks good but I guess I would need to that later. To be honest I don't want to go into grid/cluster stuff right now. I am more of a quant finance guy but less techie :) I want to keep things simple for the moment. Just want to have access to high CPUs n RAMs for a shorter period of time..explained in my comment to Ding above

Comment: @ Michael..But I guess I have already consumed by CPU credits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of what you are asking depends upon your use-case. For example, if you have work continually arriving then you will need capacity continually available. However, if it is more batch-oriented then you could start/stop capacity and even use the new **Amazon Batch** service that can allocate resources when needed and remove them when jobs are finished.

Some things to note:

- You can **change the Instance Type** when an instance is stopped. So, your t2.micro instance can be changed to a large instance (eg m4.xlarge) by stopping it, changing the instance type and starting it again.
- The t2.micro Instance Type is actually extremely powerful when CPU burst credits are available, but it limited in capability when all CPU Credits are consumed. A good machine for bursty workloads, but not continual workloads.
- Spot instances are great, but please note that they will be terminated if the Spot Price goes above your bid price. Prices vary by region, Availability Zone within a region and instance type, so you could **launch instances with a variety of attributes** (different AZs, different instance types) that would make it unlikely that you would lose all capacity at the same time. Spot can save considerable costs and is well worth investigating.
- Take a look at **Amazon EMR**, which runs Hadoop to provide parallel processing across a cluster of instances.
- **Stop instances** when you don't need them. That's the best way to get good value!

Comment: Thanks John. I think Amazon Batch would have been great but it's not available in the Asia Pacific Region. I guess all my CPU credits are consumed and that's the reason, my computations became extremely slow. Amazon EMR looks little complicated, but I will have a look later : ) What I did an hour back was to take an AMI of my existing t2.micro and created a t2.medium with the AMI and started running my computations. It was fast at first but then became slow unfortunately. So when I change my Instance type and change it to m4.large, does it keep my original EBS volume ?